# Pass HTML user input to Python variable

Tags: python, html, esp8266, micropython

I'm trying to create a webserver with micropython in access point (hotspot) mode. My problem is that I don't know how to pass simple HTML user input to a python variable (username and password).

Flask/MicroWebSrv is not an option for me due to memory issues (using an ESP8266 with limited flash and RAM) and I don't really want to rebuild my webserver from scratch. Previous solutions based on CGI package is depreciated. Any other generic method?

```
import network
import socket

ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)    
ap.active(True)                     
ap.config(essid=ap_ssid, password=ap_psw) 

s = socket.socket() 
s.bind(('', 80))  
s.listen(5)


def webpage(): 
  html = """
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1", charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Login Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="center">
         <div class="header">
            Login Form
         </div>
         <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="wifi_ssid" name="wifi_ssid">
            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            <input id="wifi_psw" name="wifi_psw" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <i class="fas fa-lock" onclick="show()"></i>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
         </form>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>"""
  return html

while True:
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  request = conn.recv(1024)
  response = webpage()
  conn.send(response)
  conn.close()
```

Comment: I have a Flask-like framework you can use (https://github.com/DavesCodeMusings/thimble)  I've run it on 8266 successfully. There are code samples in the /examples directory.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but your suggestion to create a webserver with different framework is too general in this case

Comment: If you're wanting to create your own web server, you're going to need to parse the `request` variable you have in your code to find out what the client has sent in the request body. The body is where you will find your form variables. Mozilla's developer network can help you with parsing the request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST It's not a trivial task, which is why I suggested using a framework. The ones I'm aware of for MicroPython are Microdot and Thimble. Creating your own can be good, too. You will learn a lot in the process.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong. I checked Thimble and seems right but after I briefly went through the code, it seemed no to be flexible enough for me. There is no example of parsing HTML input and it seemingly not support AP mode only STA. Anyway asyncio or uasyncio is pretty interesting staff to deep into. 

As for your suggestion, parsing the request variable should be straigthforward. I tried but always get None when I tried to save the variable into a txt in order to check the content (note print is not working with micropython and esp8266 so this is the only way i can see the content of a request)

Comment: Check the Thimble project's example directory: https://github.com/DavesCodeMusings/thimble/tree/main/examples You'll find `esp-access-point` which shows how to list AP client MAC addresses via an API call. Other examples show how to read the request body.